# Passing array from controller to view in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am new to Laravel and trying to pass a one dimensional array from controller to the view.

This is my controller function

```
 public function onedim_array()
    {
        $info = array(
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname' => 'Cena',
            'from' => 'USA'
            );

        return view('one_dim_array',  compact('info'));
    }
```

This is my view file:

```
<?php

foreach($info as $i)
{
    echo $i['firstname'];
}

?>
```

It gives me the following error:

> ErrorException in 34a7177cfbceee0b4760125499bdaca34b567c0b.php line 5:
>   Illegal string offset 'firstname' (View:
>   C:\AppServ\www\blog4\resources\views\one_dim_array.blade.php)

I don't know where I am making mistake. Please Help

Answer (score 7):

Since it's not multidimensional array, use this instead of `foreach()`:

```
$info['firstname']
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach()` allow you to traverse all items in your array. And in your code snippet

```
<?php

foreach($info as $i)
{
    echo $i['firstname'];
}

?>
```

you try to get element with index `'firstname'` from a string (in your example it will be `'John'`). If you want traverse all elements and display them, try this:

```
foreach($info as $i)
{
    echo $i;
}
```

or if you want to display specific element of your array, try this

```
echo $info['firstname'];
```

or

```
echo $info['lastname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting to accept multidimensional array to the view. I think here's the value of the array you're expecting to pass to the view

Controller code:

```
public function onedim_array()
{
    $info = array(
        array(
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname' => 'Cena',
            'from' => 'USA'
        ),
        array(
            'firstname' => 'John',
            'lastname' => 'Doe',
            'from' => 'Canada'
        ),
    );

    return view('one_dim_array',  compact('info'));
}
```

PS. Suggestion before diving to study a framework: "Master the basics of PHP first", and learn how to debug.